# PHP PDO invalid data source name

Tags: php

I am trying to connect to the database but encountered the error:  *invalid data source name*

in file adapter.php i am using PDO to make a connection to database. with the variable about host, username, password from model class.

```
    class Adapter{
    private $connectionString;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($connectionString, $username, $password){
        $this->$connectionString= $connectionString;
        $this->$username= $username;
        $this->$password= $password;
    }

    public function dbConnect(){ 
        try{

            $this->conn = new PDO($this->connectionString, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            echo "Connected successfully"; 

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            $this->conn=null;
        }  
    }

    public function dbClose(){
        $this->conn = null;
        echo "Closed successfully";
    }

}
```

model.php

```
    define 
 ('DB_CONNECTION_STRING',"mysql:dbname=vnguye24_movieDB;host=127.0.0.1");
    define('DB_USER',"root");
    define('DB_PASSWORD',"root");

    class Model{
    private $dbadapter;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->dbadapter = new Adapter(DB_CONNECTION_STRING,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

    }

    public function runDB(){
        $this->dbadapter->dbConnect(); 
    }


}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: IMHO, the `Adapter` class introduces a proprietary syntax and prevents your app from making full use of PDO, and it doesn't add any value or feature to make that worth it. Why not just use raw PDO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo.

```
$this->$connectionString= $connectionString;
$this->$username= $username;
$this->$password= $password;
```

should be

```
$this->connectionString = $connectionString;
$this->username = $username;
$this->password = $password;
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. unbelievable i made that mistake. waste a lot of time.